# Breaking circular dependancy

Tags: python, python-2.6

a.py:

```
def factory_a(name):
    return "A"

def run():
    a = factory_a("A")
    from b import factory_b 
    friend_of_a = factory_b("B")
    print(a)
    print(friend_of_a)
```

b.py:

```
def factory_b(name):
    return "B"

def run():
    b = factory_b("B")
    from a import factory_a 
    friend_of_b = factory_a("A")
    print(b)
    print(friend_of_b)
```

If the imports had been placed at the start of each module instead of in `run()` then this would not have worked due to circular imports. Therefore I'm wondering if I have solved this problem correctly by doing as I've done below. How would you have done this instead?

Comment: What do you mean? What should it do? Why isn't it valid in your opinion?

Comment: Importing inside a function is bad style, but the code appears to be nonetheless valid and functional.

Comment: I think you meant `print b` on the second file. beside that it seems fine

Comment: I don't understand your question. define `seems to work`?

Comment: @Baz a better solution would be to put `factory_a` and `factory_b` in a third file, `factories.py`

Comment: @Kevin: it's not bad style, the language makes this necessary in some cases and this is found in most popular Python open-source projects.

Comment: As I said in the other question, the problem is the dependencies. A needing B needing A is bad. Create a C that needs both A and B, or just merge A+B.

Comment: @SimeonVisser, But the Python style guide says "Imports are always put at the top of the file", and I consider that a more authoritative source of good style than any amount of popular projects.

Comment: @Kevin: it's simply not possible: there are situations where you need to import inside functions to break ties. The style guide applies to most other cases though: imports should not be at the bottom of a file or in between class/function definitions.

Answer (score 1):

The code works... now, I don´t like it. This kind of mutual dependence makes the code difficult to understand and extend. Something like this seems much better:

a.py

```
def factory_a(name):
    return "A"
```

b.py

```
def factory_b(name):
    return "B"
```

controller.py

```
from a import factory_a     
from b import factory_b     

def run_a():
    a = factory_a("A")        
    friend_of_a = factory_b("B")
    print(a)
    print(friend_of_a)

def run_b():
    b = factory_b("B")
    friend_of_b = factory_a("A")
    print(a)
    print(friend_of_b)
```